# Chrome Text Shadow Bug on Retina Display

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, retina-display

Codepen Link: https://codepen.io/calebzahnd/pen/OWxxLw

```
h1 {
  max-width: 800px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 90px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-shadow: 0 0 50px #000;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

I've found what I can only imagine to be a bug in Chrome Browsers when displaying on a Retina screen. There is a strange clipping on the text shadow, and the text shadow itself is pushed way below the actual text. When adjusting the font-size, the clipping will randomly change to only clip certain characters. If you adjust the blue value of the text-shadow, certain values will snap the shadow back to where it should be located, but without any sort of rhyme or reason. I've checked and this displays fine on Safari and Firefox. Can someone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I can perfectly see the text shadowing in Chrome and Safari browser with my retina display screen.
Try updating your browsers and/or clean your cache.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: In viewing this on other retina displays, it seems inconsistent. Some monitors display it correctly, others clip the shadow, and where and how it clips the shadow seems to be inconsistent as well.

Answer (score 1):

```css
h1 {
 max-width: 800px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 90px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-shadow: 0 0 50px #000;
        margin-left:25px;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is what you want everyone to see</h1>
```

The problem is that there is this large shadow, and the text is right against the pixel edge. Some devices/browsers won't render past the pixel edge of a window or a div. My suggestion is a 25px margin to the left of your text. Perhaps even 25 all around.